# Compare each character in string with another character using conditional IF

Tags: python

I am used to using C++ and relatively new to python. 
In the code attached below I am comparing a string with a character .
Trying to solve this problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/defanging-an-ip-address/

```
def defangIPaddr(self, address: str) -> str:

    for i in address:
        if address[i] == ".":
            address = address[:i-1] + "[" + address[i] + "]" +address[i+1] 
    print(address)
```

I am getting an errror in line 3 , due to incorrect syntax.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `address.replace(".", "[.]")` doesn't do it? As for your error, *i* is a character **not** an index (*for* loop equivalent to `for (auto element : container)`).

Comment: `i` is a character not an numeric index. So `if i == "."` is sufficient.

Comment: You should post your actual error here

Comment: FWIW there is no "character" in Python, only  1-lengthed strings

Comment: Being new doesn't prevent from doing the official tutorial, quite on the contrary: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `address = address[:i-1] + "[" + address[i] + "]" +address[i+1] ` to do

Comment: Try `for i in "abc.de": print(i)` and meditate over the result.

Comment: As for the next problem you will encounter: modifying a sequence while you're iterating through it is extremely unlikely to be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonic solution: use `str.replace()`:

```
address = address.replace(".", "[.]")
```

Now if you really want to make it with a for loop, you first need to properly use for loops - [a Python for loop is a "foreach" kind of loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), then to build a new string from it - the pythonic way being to build a list and then `str.join` it back into a string:

```
parts = []
for item in address:
    if item == ".":
         item = "[.]"
    parts.append(item)
address = "".join(parts)
```

or more simply:

```
address = "".join("[.]" if item == "." else item for item in address)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in address` means that `i` represents each element in the list. Use

```py
for i in range(0,len(address)):
```

to make `i` a sequence of numbers instead.

Comment: or better use the for loop as expected, eventually with `enumerate()` if you need the indices too.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment explains, `i` in its current form is a character. You can use it to build another string:

```
defanged=""
for i in address:
    if address[i] == ".":
        defanged = defanged + "[.]"
    else:
        defanged = defanged + i
print(defanged)
```

or join a list/generator (it is a generator here):

```
defanged = "".join("[.]" if i=="." else i for i in address)
print(defanged)
```

or just use `replace()`:

```
defanged = address.replace(".","[.]")
print(defanged)
```

Looping over the original string-length and modifying it at the same time will not work, as when you replace a `.` with `[.]`, the string will become longer, but a `for in range` loop in Python will not adjust to the new length (as the range is set at the beginning). But in fact this direct approach would not work in C/C++ either, as after replacing `.` with  `[.]` and stepping to the "next" character, it will be a `.` again.

Test code: https://ideone.com/kASg5w